# Link MSSQL with MSQL Express between two different servers

Tags: sql-server

So this in the challenge. I have two servers in two different places (so they have two different static IP addresses). One of them is supposed to be a host (windows server 2012 with MSSQL Server 2014). I need to link this datebase with another server - mssql express.

I was trying to use MSSQL Management Studio -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers. Of course with all the hints I found in google. Still no luck. The best respond I got was "connection was established but login fail". And of course I was trying all the posibilities with 'Security' tab and 'be made using this security context'

Has anybody had such problem? Should I open sql port in router configuration?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exqm4.png)

Comment: *"connection was established but login fail"* this suggests that you were either attempting to use an AD account that doesn't have a `LOGIN` on the other instance, or a you were providing the incorrect credentials for the SQL Authentication account. Did you check the remote isntance's logs to see what the authentication error was?

Comment: Agreed it sounds like authentication failure. Doesn't sound like it's a firewall problem, otherwise you wouldn't have got a connection

Comment: Sry guys... I just did not expect the answer so fast. And sry again I was writing as I rememberd it. I just make a test, and so paste the full respond to main post

Comment: the problem i solved. The only one thing was to open 1433 and 1434 port. After it linking datebases was easy